# How do I implement a custom MIB in PySNMP?

Tags: python, mib, pysnmp

I already have the MIB text file (do I need to make this into a .py file somehow??). I am trying to use PySNMP (not net-snmp). I have been able to connect to my device and print out some info, but the info was not very helpful (just ObjectName, ObjectIdentifier, etc). I want to be able to communicate with the device (send commands to change and read values), but all of the tutorials I have seen seem to be of little help. Does anyone know how I can use my custom MIB to effectively communicate with my device? Any good sites I am missing? http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/ is ok, but I need something else...

Comment: Does your device already support the commands you wish? Or are you designing those from scratch yourself?

Comment: Did you find this one: http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/ ? The SNMP subpackage, specifically. If so, what did you think of it?

Comment: @sarnold: yes, my device is supposed to already have SNMP enabled.

Comment: @Keith: it looks like pycopia does not support SNMPv3, which seems to be the best version to use.

Comment: @superagentintern Well, most places actually use v2c in practice. v3 could be added, but it hasn't been necessary...

Answer (score 7):

To use MIBs with pysnmp you should first convert your MIB into pysnmp format (which is a collection of Python objects). The conversion is done with the pysnmp/tools/build-pysnmp-mib shell script in the following manner:

```
$ sh build-pysnmp-mib -h
build-pysnmp-mib: illegal option -- h
Convert MIB text file into PySNMP-compliant module, see http://pysnmp.sf.net.
Usage: build-pysnmp-mib [-o pysnmp-mib-file ] [ mib-text-file ]
```

Make sure you also have libsmi installed (pysnmp scripts use the smidump tool from libsmi distribution).

Unless you put your new pysnmp MIB file into pysnmp/smi/mibs/ (which is not a good idea), you would also have to point pysnmp to the location where your own MIBs are. This could be done as explained [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/faq.html#4).

Once you are done with the MIB, you can use it from your scripts as explained [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/4.x/v3arch/oneliner/manager/withmib/setgen.html).

You could make a quick check how your new MIB works by invoking pysnmpget/pysnmpset tools shipped with the pysnmp-apps package.

BTW, chances are that the MIB you need to work with is already converted into pysnmp format and distributed with the pysnmp-mibs package.

Comment: Is there any way to convert the MIB on Windows 7? Cygwin sounds like it might work, but I'm having issues with downloading/installing. Will PowerShell work?

Comment: Have no experience with Cygwin. The conversion also works out of the box on MacOS X once you build libsmi there.